# Liferay | I lost login portlet

Tags: authentication, liferay

I was reviewing some liferay tables, and deleted records do not remember. I believe was in `ResourcePermissions`.

Now, when I see the homepage of my Liferay, "Login" link doesn't show. And when I access the url http://host:8080/c/portal/login doesn't show login form. What records must exist to run the login?

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations, you've learnt the most important lesson when an application uses a database to store its internal state: Despite the possibility to view the content with database tools, writing to the database (without going through the application itself) may result in data loss. In fact, typically it *will* result in data loss - some realize it immediately while others realize it after 6 months of operation. Unfortunately the later group does not attribute their experienced failure to the modification of the database.

From that point of view: You're luckily in the first group, so that you'll learn for the future to *never* change Liferay's database again.

Can I give you the records that are required? *No*. Will you be able to restore your database when you create a few records? *No*. But what if you can? *You will be in the second group mentioned above*: You will have missed other manipulations that you did today, and these will surface some time in the future when you don't attribute it to today any more.

How to recover?

- Restore your backup
- Create a new Liferay installation and import your content to that version

Does this help? Well, if you need to get at your current content, you can try to log in by accessing your portal at the URL `http://localhost:8080/c/portal/login`.

This is a long winded answer (of which you probably only wanted to hear that last URL - if it works). I hope that it changes the way you treat the database in future.

Comment: "Create a new Liferay installation and import your content to that version"   I think we does not required to re-installation  liferay. We can set setup-wizard key value to true in portal-setup-wizart.properties. Liferay will ask again for configuration and add new database in this configuration.

Comment: well - reset the database is the key. But if the existing document library still exists, Liferay might complain about (old) binary data that it does not have any metadata for. Lucene index might be another issue.  People who have messed with the database typically also mess with other parts of the installation. Whatever you do - if you start over clean, you're starting over clean - nothing beats that.